# Прочитать затенённое приватное поле внешнего класса

Tags: javascript, инкапсуляция

Я ожидал, что находясь в классе `B` я смогу для инстанса класса `A` прочитать поля `#a` и `#x`, однако фактически у меня читается только `#a`, а при попытке прочитать `#x` происходит ошибка

> Cannot read private member #x from an object whose class did not declare it

Выходит, что поле `#x` класса `B` затеняет аналогичное поле класса `A`? Во-первых, это выглядит как-то нелогично - почему так происходит и, если так задумано, то с какой целью? Во-вторых, есть ли какой-то способ прочитать `#x` на инстансе класса `A`?

```js
class A {
  #a = "A#a"
  #x = "A#x"

  static B = class B {
    #b = "B#b"
    #x = "B#x"

    static doSmth(obj) {
      try { console.log(obj.#a) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#b) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#x) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
    }
  }
}

console.log("=== A ===")
A.B.doSmth(new A)
console.log("")
console.log("=== B ===")
A.B.doSmth(new A.B)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
.as-console-row.as-console-row:after { content: none }
```

Если это важно, я использую Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90.

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/66670747/4928642)

Comment: Вопрос от админа. Всем работать над ответом :))

Answer (score 0):

Дам кусочек [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

> Приватные поля экземпляров объявляются #имя (произносится как "хэш
> нэймс"), которые идентифицируются префиксом #. # является частью
> имени, а также используется для объявления и доступа.
>
> **Инкапсуляция обеспечивается языком. Обращение к # именам вне области
> видимости является синтаксической ошибкой.**

Вы передали **A** методу в **B**

```
A.B.doSmth(new A)

A#a
Cannot read private member #b from an object whose class did not declare it
Cannot read private member #x from an object whose class did not declare it
```

Метод пытается вызвать как бы A#x но так как B#x также существует он отказывает в доступе к нему.

Далее Вы передали **B** методу в **В**

```
A.B.doSmth(new A.B)

Cannot read private member #a from an object whose class did not declare it
B#b
B#x
```

Метод пытается вызвать как бы A#а но так как B не имеет доступа он отказывает в доступе к нему.

```js
class A {
  #a = "A#a"
  #b = "A#b"
  #x = "A#x"
  
  static doSmthA(obj) {
      try { console.log(obj.#a) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#b) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#x) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
  }

  static B = class B {
    
    #a = "B#a"
    #b = "B#b"
    #x = "B#x"

    static doSmthB(obj) {
      try { console.log(obj.#a) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#b) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
      try { console.log(obj.#x) } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
    }
  }
}

console.log("=== A ===")
A.doSmthA(new A)
console.log("")
console.log("=== B ===")
A.B.doSmthB(new A.B)

console.log("=== Ну и веселье ===")
console.log("=== A ===")
A.doSmthA(new A.B)
console.log("")
console.log("=== B ===")
A.B.doSmthB(new A)
```

**Если подитожить - приватные поля не видны вне класса и не важно откуда вы их вызываете.**

Comment: Только на вопрос, зачем так сделано, это не отвечает.

Comment: @Querty Последнее обновление.